# Nested Routes with RoutingAutoBundle (Symfony CMF)

Tags: symfony, symfony-cmf

I imagine this is a simple enough thing. I just want to use the RoutingAutoBundle for **nested** pages.

I'm following along here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/cookbook/creating_a_cms/

Say I have `Page` documents which have a parent.

```
/**
 * 
 * @PHPCR\Document(referenceable=true)
 * 
 * @author Matt Durak <mattdurak@gmail.com>
 */
class Page implements RouteReferrersReadInterface
{
    /**
     * @PHPCR\Id()
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @PHPCR\ParentDocument()
     */
    protected $parent;

    //...

    /**
     * Get ID
     * 
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    public function setParent($parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    // ...
}
```

My auto routing configuration is like so:

```
cmf_routing_auto:
    mappings:
        Study\MainBundle\Document\Page:
            content_path:
                pages:
                    provider: [specified, { path: /cms/routes/page }]
                    exists_action: auto_increment
                    not_exists_action: create
            content_name:
                provider: [content_method, { method: getTitle }]
                exists_action: auto_increment
                not_exists_action: create
```

I would like something like the following. Assume I have my data like so:

```
/cms/pages
     /page-1
     /page-2
         /page-A
         /page-B
```

Currently, those 4 pages would have the following routes

```
/page/page-1
/page/page-2
/page/page-A
/page/page-B
```

I would like

```
/page/page-1
/page/page-2
/page/page-2/page-A
/page/page-2/page-B
```

I've tried adding another `content_path` with the `content_object` provider and calling `getParent`, but that did not work. Is anyone familiar with Symfony CMF and the RoutingAutoBundle that knows how to do this? Documentation is sparse...

Comment: How should the URLs look like? (btw, the bundle is fully documented, it's still in beta though, so it is missing some tips&tricks arricles))

Comment: Added the routes I see and the routes I'd like. Yes, the documentation is missing any useful examples beyond the basics. That would be really helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use the content_method provider and return either null or the parent in the class. As of RoutingAutoBundle alpha10, a provider is allowed to not add anything to the path.

The code would look like:

```
cmf_routing_auto:
    mappings:
        Study\MainBundle\Document\Page:
            content_path:
                pages:
                    provider: [specified, { path: /cms/routes/page }]
                    exists_action: auto_increment
                    not_exists_action: create
                parent:
                    provider: [content_method, { method: getParentPath }]
                    exists_action: use
                    not_exists_action: create
            content_name:
                provider: [content_method, { method: getTitle }]
                exists_action: auto_increment
                not_exists_action: create
```

```php
class Page
{
    // ...

    public function getParentPath()
    {
        return $this->parent instanceof static ? $this->parent->getTitle() : null;
    }
}
```

---

You could also use content_object, but that one is planned to be removed from the bundle.

Comment: The `null` doesn't seem to work. And if I return an empty string, it says that is not allowed. "Notice: Undefined variable: object in D:\web_workspace\study\vendor\symfony-cmf\routing-auto-bundle\Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\R
outingAutoBundle\AutoRoute\PathProvider\ContentMethodProvider.php on line 82"