# How to addsub pages to Sylius

Tags: symfony, sylius, symfony-cmf

Is there a way to create pages in Sylius with the following structure:

```
top-level-a    
top-level-a/sub-level-a-1
top-level-a/sub-level-a-2
top-level-b
top-level-b/sub-level-b-1
top-level-b/sub-level-b-2
```

I have only been able to create top-level pages.

I'm looking to do this in Sylius administration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested Routes with RoutingAutoBundle (Symfony CMF)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816591/nested-routes-with-routingautobundle-symfony-cmf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not possible out of the box.

This part of the admin is 99% only symfony-cmf stuff, sylius got it only included. It probably will be done at some point but for sure it won't be before 1.0.0 stable release of sylius.

If you want nested pages, you can extend the class.
Exact same question is here, with answer:

[Nested Routes with RoutingAutoBundle (Symfony CMF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816591/nested-routes-with-routingautobundle-symfony-cmf)

Comment: Ok thank you. For now I will create my own bundle and work around it.